# if I want Elasticsearch to be faster, do I just add more nodes to the cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

Seems that Kibana will take over 30 seconds for some of my queries and subsequently cancel the requests automatically.  Kinda a bummer because I was hoping that a single node, a dual Master/Data node would be enough.  It seems this might not be the case, and to improve the query speed I should add additional Nodes (Data I think) to help with processing things faster.

That being said, is this a natural thing for Kibana 7.6?  Will it auto Cancel requests after 30 seconds, or can this be disabled?  I was hoping to have a single node for the time being and was OK with nodes taking time to process as I really only query to monitor the throughput for the time being.

It seems that if I do want to improve query times, I should most certainly look into adding an additional data node (or 2) to improve query capabilities, but not necessarily the indexing, as it is still chugging along at a smooth 2m entries per 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You can cancel searches by calling [task management API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#task-cancellation). Kibana does cancel query from [7.4](http://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/42035), as documented:

> In-progress search requests to Elasticsearch will now be cancelled
>   when a new search is requested, or when a user navigates away from the
>   page or removes a panel from a dashboard.

That's mainly a protection from multiple requests by a single kibana client, not a timeout cancel. If you keep waiting and perform no other operations, you can get search/aggregation results eventually.

**ORIGIN POST**

> Will it auto Cancel requests after 30 seconds, or can this be disabled?

A query in ES will run, there is no timeout. Kibana just do not get responses that take too long to return. To configure this timeout, `kibana.yaml` has the following (default) settings:

```
# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or elasticsearch.
# This must be > 0
request_timeout: 300000
```

Instead of kibana, you can write a java client for your requests or use `curl` to call ES REST API. Usually this can achieve a much longer timeout.

> It seems that if I do want to improve query times, I should most certainly look into adding an additional data node (or 2) to improve query capabilities

Multiple factors influence ES query performance and it's more wise to focus on real bottleneck.
CPU usage, memory usage, disk throughput, network bandwidth, etc. It's better to make clear what's the bottleneck. Adding nodes, using SSD instead of SATA, or adding memory may also help.

Comment: kibana does cancel query from 7.4 -> https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/42035 , you may want to edit answer as OP is using 7.6 . Also recent versions of elasticsearch can cancel query .

Comment: Kibana Devs confirmed on their forums that Kibana does cancel requests. By Default 30 seconds if not defined in the yaml.   That being said, I do think it is important to focus more on the bottleneck as well.  Adding more machines just kicks the cans down the road and will crop up later.

That being said, I presume that i should likely just look at ES than kibana.  If i want to improve ES then I think i should take a look at my logstash and possibly update the the datatypes for indexing on datetime and other properties.  Also, I am curious if i can reindex a current instance based on props.